# How to find 3 or more length of alphabetic in select by attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image]

How to find 3 or more length of alphabetic in select by attributes. Below highlighted fields need to select please tell me the query to find through select by attributes in arc map.

Comment: Try CHAR_LENGTH(string_exp)

Comment: Those all are select with numeric combination also but i need only alphabetic.

Comment: could you please let me know the query of above situation.

Comment: Populate new field using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string/12851835#12851835